# PHP Select Value in MySQL Using Greater Than and Less Than

Tags: php, mysql

I have been racking my brains trying to get something that seems simple to work. I have a TABLE "weight". Weight has 3 columns "shipping_to", "shipping_from", and "shipping_cost".

Shipping_to and Shipping_from are the weight values and shipping cost holds the shipping cost if the value is greater than or equal to X AND less than or equal to X.

I have written this a million different ways and for the life of me it won't work.

UPDATED:
The Script works  "kind of" but it never returns a success response of 1 and it never fimds the value of X even though I have manually put these values into my MySQL db.

PHP SCRIPT:

```
if($The_Function=="SHIPPING_COST"){
    $response = array();

    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    $con = new DB_CONNECT();

    $ship_weight = 1;


    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM weight WHERE from_weight >= '$ship_weight' AND to_weight <= '$ship_weight'");

    if(!empty($result)){
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $response["userID"] = array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $custID = array();
                $custID["shipping_cost"] = $row["shipping_cost"];
                array_push($response["userID"], $custID);
            }
            $response["success"] = 1;

            echo json_encode($response);
        }else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No shipping found";

            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No shipping found";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on what is not working ie: what value are you getting - this way it helps which section we should be looking at.

Comment: Added more info above.

Comment: from_weight >= '$ship_weight' AND to_weight <= '$ship_weight' - which weight is larger and smaller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was in the Query itself. All I had to do was give the last Column something to compare to so I just added $ship_weight again. Here is the code.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM weight WHERE '$ship_weight' >= from_weight AND  '$ship_weight' <= to_weight");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `$result` will never be `empty()`

If the query works if will be a `resource handle` and if it fails it will be `false`.

So try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM weight WHERE from_weight >= '$ship_weight' AND to_weight <= '$ship_weight'");

if($result !== FALSE){
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $response["userID"] = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $custID = array();
            $custID["shipping_cost"] = $row["shipping_cost"];
            array_push($response["userID"], $custID);
        }
        $response["success"] = 1;

        echo json_encode($response);
    }else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No shipping found";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No shipping found";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: `$a = false; echo empty($a);` prints 1

Comment: The script I posted does run and the $result will be empty if there is nothing that meets the Query Request.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a copy and paste of your code?  If so, look at this line:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM weight WHERE from_weight >= '$ship_weight' AND to_weight <= '$ship_weight'");
```

PHP is considering your `$ship_weight` variable as part of the string.  Change it to:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM weight WHERE from_weight >= '".$ship_weight."' AND to_weight <= '".$ship_weight."'");
```

Also, mysql_* is deprecated.  Take a look at the [mysqli_* extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).